# How a fetch data async in Nuxt 3 using a plugin

Tags: async-await, fetch, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I want to fetch data async in Nuxt 3 and show the result in my template by use a variable. How I can realize it? If I use my code I got "[object Promise]"

app.vue

```
<template>

<div>{{$translate('1')}}</div>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const { $translate } = useNuxtApp()

</script>
```

myplugin.ts

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {

async function loadData(translate_id: string){

    return await $fetch('/api/translation/' + "?translation_id=" + translate_id + "&language=de", {
        method: 'GET',
    });

}

    return {
        provide: {
            translate: async (translate_id: string) => await loadData(translate_id)
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `translate()` as `async` function, you need to use `await`.

```
<template>

<div>{{ result }}</div>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const 
  { $translate } = useNuxtApp(),
  result = await $translate('1');

</script>
```